# Find files with later versions

Tags: regex, perl

I have a folder with about a thousand files in it.

There are a few hundred files with duplicates with the string `(2)` at the end of the file name.

What would be the easiest way to find the filenames with that suffix and delete the original files which don't have the `(2)` in the name?

Comment: You will get much better replies if you appear to have tried to write something yourself. You shouldn't be asking for your work to be done for free.

Comment: Sorry I did some reserch but as I'm quite new to any coding or scripting and I'm not a native speaker I was happy with my question as it was. Thank you for improving the grammar, you deleted the right keyword though.

Comment: I imagine that you are learning, and most of us will understand you if you do your best with English. But you should read about Perl for a few days and try something that you think might work. It would be easy for you to write something that said you wanted to learn, but you ask only for a solution.

Comment: I like to see solutions to problems that way I can learn better, I bet there are a lot of helpful guys here who don't mind to show how to do it.

Comment: If that is what you like then that is what will become your habit. If you are someone who likes to fill out puzzle books from the answers in the back then you will never master the problems. Perl is very well documented, and you should have a `perldoc` command with your installation. Please take a few weeks to read what you already have, which includes multiple examples, and then come back here to advise as well as hoping for help.

Comment: I didn't specifically  want an answer involving perl, you deleted the powershell and pcregrep tag. I already have my own solution, by reading documentation.

Comment: I have tried to help you. `pcgrep` and `powershell` are poor solutions to your problem. Are you working on Windows? Which version? Have you tried anything at all? Why are you so angry when we ask what you have done for yourself?

Comment: It is on windows, but since the subsystem for linux is also available, I can also use the tools provided by ubuntu.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the solution, after a bit of reading technet. I used powershell at the end to delete the files without the sufix and keep the newer ones. I like oneliners so i came up with this:

```
Remove-Item ((Get-ChildItem).FullName -match ".+\(2\).+" -replace "(.+)\s\(2\)(.+)",'$1$2')
```

I'm sure it's not the best solution but it worked.

Comment: This is not a solution to your problem. It uses neither Perl nor regular expressions

Comment: You are a bit strange, it was you, who deleted the powershell and pcregrep tag from my question smarty.

Comment: *"I have found the solution, after a bit of reading technet"* That reading should have preceded your shout to the world to fix your problem. Stack Overflow is a resort where people who know what they are doing can ask their peers for help. It isn't for *"I want to print 1 to 10. How to do it?"*. You have a dreadful solution. Stop, and do some more reading.

Comment: I am reading continuosly, then I had this very bad idea to ask a question here. As I see this is not the place to ask for help. This is the place where someone edit your question then try to make you look bad, insted of helping.

Comment: So you know that most questions provide a lot of explanation, and show what has been written. I think you don't know what tools you have. Your question has three down votes, and none of them are mine. I am trying to help, and you shouldn't be angry.

Answer (score 3):

Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $dir = shift;

for my $file (glob "$dir/*(2)") {
    my $original = substr $file, 0, -3;
    unlink $original if -f $original;
}
```

Specify the directory name as the argument. For explanation, see

- [shift](http://p3rl.org/shift)
- [glob](http://p3rl.org/glob)
- [substr](http://p3rl.org/substr)
- [-f](http://p3rl.org/-x)

Comment: Thanks for the help choroba, At the end I find a simpler solution. I tried to use pcregrep from bash at first with similar aproach as the solution that I came up with, but i couldn't replace the matching string with the multiple capturing groups.

Comment: I downvoted this because there is clearly a versioning system, and the real requirement is to update everything to the latest version. So there may be a `file(4)` and a `file(6)` whose fate no one has prescribed. I don't believe we should take questions as job specifications, either on principal or as hints to what is required.

Comment: There is no file with greater then (2) in the name, and there won't be anymore files in this case. The original files are corrupted, and the ones with the suffix are the correct ones.